# question on listview control (windows forms)

Tags: winforms, listview

I use a listview control that displays search results over text files.What I want to do is to limit  access to readonly when user clicks.Is there any simple solution to the problem?Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a .readonly property? eg myListView.readonly or something I know it shows up in the Properties panel in the Designer Also, is this C#, or vb or soemthing else .NET

Comment: Very unclear, readonly *what*?  There's only one kind of editing supported by ListView, you disable it by setting the LabelEdit property to False (the default).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34122841/making-listview-columns-read-only.aspx) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/6cec829f-8f5f-4476-a2fc-772d155e7e6d). You have to make the columns read-only. Check for properties like readonly, labeledit, editable etc. Must be possible. Else the links will help you further. I use DevExpress grids and there it's easily possible (but those components are very customizable and much more advanced than standard Microsoft .NET ui components imho).